# Make a HTTP header request with Curb

Tags: ruby, curl, curb

With curl I can perform a HTTP header request like so:

```
curl -I 'http://www.google.com'
```

How can I perform this procedure with Curb? I don't want to retrieve the body as this would take too much time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-I/--head` option performs a `HEAD` request. With libcurl C API you need to set the [CURLOPT_NOBODY](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTNOBODY) option.

With curb, you can set this option on your handle as follow:

```
h = Curl::Easy.new("http://www.google.com")
h.set :nobody, true
h.perform
puts h.header_str
# HTTP/1.1 302 Found
# Location: http://www.google.fr/
# Cache-Control: private
# Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
# ...
```

As an alternative, you can use one of the convenient shortcut like:

```
h = Curl::Easy.new("http://www.google.com")
# This sets the option behind the scenes, and call `perform`
h.http_head
puts h.header_str
# ...
```

Or like this one, using the class method:

```
h = Curl::Easy.http_head("http://www.google.com")
puts h.header_str
# ...
```

---

*Note: the ultimate shortcut is `Curl.head("http://www.google.com")`. That being said wait until the next curb release before using it, since it's **NOT** working at the time of writing, and has just been patched: see this [pull request](https://github.com/taf2/curb/pull/148).*